# Вычитание из функции Date

Tags: дата, php

Доброго всем здравия.
Делаю одну штуковину, нужна дата от вчера.

```
$vdate = (date("d")-1).".".date( "m.Y");
```

формат `date("d")` даёт числа в формате: `01-31` с нулями.
Это мне и нужно, но моё вычисление **date("d")-1** ломает формат и отбирает **0**, вроде и понятно:
**08-1=7**, но как этого избежать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$vdate = date('d.m.Y', strtotime('yesterday'));
```

Comment: Спасибо! заработало!

Answer (score 2):

А как насчёт использовать класс [Datetime](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.datetime.php), в нём есть [очень удобный метод для этой цели](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.sub.php).
ИМХО, манипулировать классом намного проще чем строкой.
Я вот не могу понять, почему люди создают запутанный код, в котором, порой, сами не смогут разобраться.

Comment: я не против использования классов, но в данном случае это проще?:

    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    $vdate = $date->format('d.m.Y');

Comment: @inso на вкус и цвет все фломастера разные. Не далече, чем вчера обсуждал с коллегой подобный момент и сошлись что лучше 3 строчки быстро читаемого кода чем одна не очень. В данном случае, всё зависит от того, кому какой инструмент удобней использовать для своих повседневных задач ;)

Comment: под "3 строчки быстро читаемого кода" я имел ввиду, что не надо особо напрягаться, что бы вникнуть и код читается программистом как обычный текст.